# Texlive-2020's lualatex fails to compile due to "no writeable cache path". Texlive-2019's lualatex works fine

Tags: luatex, texlive-2019, texlive-2020

After upgrading my texlive distribution to v2020 on my linux machine `lualatex` stopped working altogether producing the same fatal error for all projects. Even compiling the following minimal source file *main.tex* using `lualatex --interaction=batchmode main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

yields the following errors:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)
 restricted system commands enabled.
luaotfload | load : FATAL ERROR
luaotfload | load :   × Failed to load "fontloader" module "basics-gen".
luaotfload | load :   × Error message:
luaotfload | load :     × "...020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:301: system : no writeable cache path, quiting".
stack traceback:
        ...ive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.lua:206: in local 'load_fontloader_module'
        ...020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:303: in upvalue 'init_main'
        ...020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-init.lua:584: in function 'luaotfload-init.lua'
        ...ive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.lua:330: in field 'main'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk
```

The Texlive-2019 version of `lualatex` as well as both `pdflatex` versions work fine and produce an empty document without errors.

As I've used the official texlive installer and its suggested default settings to install both distributions (to */usr/local/texlive/2019/...* and */usr/local/texlive/2020/...*, respectively) I am utterly clueless as to what may be the problem here since I haven't had any problems with the 2019 distribution.

Any help? Thanks!

**update**: I managed to get it to work by explicitly setting the `TEXMFVAR` environment variable to *$HOME/.texlive2020/texmf-var* which is the default value suggested by the installer script. Did I make a mistake during the installation process? I didn't have to export the envvar before.

---

The output of `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFCACHE` is

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var:/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! What is the output of `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFCACHE` on your system (under TeX Live 2020)?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I updated the question to contain the output. Does that suggest what the problem might be?

Comment: For some reason you got a weird TEXMFVAR, but it's hard to say why. You might want to look into "/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf.cnf". Maybe you set TEXMFVAR to something there? (e.g. because you changed it in the installer)

Comment: The texmf.cnf explicitly listed TEXMFVAR = TEXMFSYSVAR which may explain the problem. I set TEXMFVAR = $HOME/.cache/texlive2020/texmf-var which solves the problem without having to export any environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like something went wrong during installation, causing the cache direcory setting to refer to a path owned by root.

I manually set the `TEXTMFHOME` and `TEXMFVAR` parameters inside the */usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf.cnf* configuration file to refer to local directories which solved the problem.

```
TEXMFHOME = $HOME/.cache/texlive2020
TEXMFVAR = $HOME/.cache/texlive2020/texmf-var/
TEXMFCONFIG = $TEXMFSYSCONFIG
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem.  My profile on Windows contained an UTF-8 character. After I changed that the problem dissapeared. [That was a whole process!]